# PHPReport : Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Could not close zip file

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I was gettingerror "Cannot close zip file.." and realized it didn't have permissions to write to that directory. 
here my code:

```
    $template = 'myexcel1.xls';
    //set absolute path to directory with template files
    $templateDir = __DIR__ . "/../controllers/";

    //set config for report
    $config = array(
    'template' => $template,
    'templateDir' => $templateDir
    );


    //load template
    $R = new PHPReport($config);
  //  print_r($R); die();
    $R->load(array(
        'id' => 'scenario_input',
        'repeat' => TRUE,
        'data' => $data   
        )
    );
   // print_r($R); die();
    // define output directoy 
    $output_file_dir = 'opt/lampp/htdocs/randema/';

    $output_file_excel = $output_file_dir  . 'Myexcel1.xls';
    //download excel sheet with data in /tmp folder
    $result = $R->render('excel', $output_file_excel);
```

Comment: Is this an answer to some other question? If so post it as an answer to that question even if the question was yours. Thats quite legal

Comment: Otherwise this is likely to get you even more downvotes!!!!

Comment: is this not answer other question , its my error when generate excel sheet using phpreport liberies

Comment: But it is not a question, its an answer!

Comment: And if the answer is check your unix file permissions its been answered a 100 times already

Comment: if its answer ? why i am getting error when generate excel sheet..

Comment: You say that there's an exception, and in your first sentence you say that it's because of file permissions. There's your answer right there. Unless you're still having issues, or something else is going on, in which case you'll need to be more specific.